# Sudo cannot find a file that exists in EC2 instance when running in an ebextension config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, config

I have an elastic beanstalk instance and I can access the underlying EC2 using SSM and when I do so I can clearly see this file `/etc/sudoers.d/ssm-agent-users` exists however, when I add the following command to an ebextension config:

```
01-command:
  command: sudo sed -i '/ssm-user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL/d' /etc/sudoers.d/ssm-agent-users
```

it shows this error while attempting to deploy the EB instance:

```
Command failed on instance. Return code: 2 Output: sed: can't read /etc/sudoers.d/ssm-agent-users: No such file or directory. command 01-command in .ebextensions/05_run_startup_script.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Does anyone know why I can clearly see the file when accessing the EC2 using a session but the ebextension command cannot seem to find the same file?

For anyone curious, I am trying to automatically disable SSM access for the instance at launch time.

Comment: Any reason why you do this this way? You can deny permissions to SSM by simply not giving your instance role SSM permissions.

Comment: I believe for security reasons to stop someone with IAM access from just granting SSM permissions back to a role without them if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

`ssm-agent-users` file is only **created after** the first SSM Session Manager login. Thus, no new instances will have this file out of the box.

But if you want to block Session Manager, you can `Deny` its permissions in your instance role. The permissions are shown [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/getting-started-add-permissions-to-existing-profile.html).

Comment: Yeah we can do it through IAM I guess if there's no alternative. Would you happen to know if this could work though as an alternative `sudo yum erase amazon-ssm-agent –y`? I believe it basically uninstalls the SSM agent altogether.

Comment: @new-dev-123 I still don't understand. What does it solve if you remove it? Anyone can still install it later on. That's why you have IAM permissions that control access to SSM.